# No Signal with SDI to HDMI Converter

Tags: video, streaming, hdmi, sdi

So I am trying to connect 4 security cameras to a TV using a quad splitter. I am using one camera right now to test the connections. Here is my set up:

I have a security camera with with an SDI output connected by male-male BNC to a quad splitter.

[image: Here is the security camera]

The video1 connection on the splitter is to the camera. The video out connection is to the SDI to HDMI converter.

[image: This is the Quadsplitter]

The HDMI output from the converter connects to a SAMSUNG flatscreen TV. However when a connection is established between the converter and a source, the source button lights up. However the button does not light up green on the converter and the TV displays a "No Signal Message" (not a no cable connected message). I know all the power sources are connected (there is no indication on the camera however to let me know whether it is on or off when connected to DC12V supply, but the quad splitter should produce some feed itself from what I've seen). What am I doing wrong? Sorry this is a long question, thank you for all your help in advance!

Comment: Many questions arise : are you sure the green BNC from the camera is an SDI signal ? Can you test the output of the quad splitter directly in an SDI monitor ? Can you test the output of the SDI to HDMI converter with another trusted SDI source ? Can you provide the references of the camera, quad splitter and SDI to HDMI converter ?

Comment: Ok you may have given me a hint at what my problem is. The guy at radioshack just told me to get male to male bnc cables because that connected to all the output/input ports on the camera and splitter. However, i didnt know there were different types of bnc cables. I bought this: "CableWholesale 6-Feet RG58 AU Stranded BNC Cable, Braided (10X1-01106) Sold by: cables4computer" from Amazon. Its a male to male bnc but it doesnt say HD-SDI. Is that where I went wrong? Thank you. @audionuma

Comment: I will provide links to the splitter, the camera, and the converter in around 40 minutes, thanks for your help. @audionuma

Comment: **Quadsplitter:**  http://www.amazon.com/VideoSecu-Security-Surveillance-Splitter-Processor/dp/B00108HEKK/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1438009624&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=quadsplitter  **Security Camera:** http://www.amazon.com/GW-Security-Megapixel-Outdoor-Infrared/dp/6406514327/ref=sr_1_19?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1438009698&sr=1-19&keywords=hd+1080p+security+camera  **Converter:**  http://www.amazon.com/AVUE-Converter-Support-3G-SDI-HD-SDI/dp/B008D7VJ5M/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1438009769&sr=1-1&keywords=avue+hdmi+sdi  @audionuma

Comment: Should I have bought these cables instead? http://www.amazon.com/RiteAV-6FT-Video-Cable-Digital/dp/B00EBAGUFO/ref=sr_1_11?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1438009510&sr=1-11&keywords=hd+sdi+cable   @audionuma

Comment: Ok so I got the camera to display on the TV using the same BNC cables. Everything seems to work until I add the quadsplitter into the mix. Shouldnt the same bnc cables work from the quadsplitter to the converter as the camera to the converter (all SDI ports are the same). @audionuma

Comment: As far as I can tell after reading the quad splitter product page, this product does not support SDI, although it has BNC connectors. Seems to be composite video (the one usually found on a yellow rca connector in consumer products), on the inputs as well as on the outputs.